# BIOS function e820 always returns the same result

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, osdev

I've been working on my operating system. To detect the memory map, I use the BIOS function `e820` but it always returns the same value.

I first wrote the code in Assembly, which I actually copied from OSDev wiki so I am sure that there is no error in the code then wire the code to the C code by a pointer to the `ES:DI`. Here is my assembly code:

```
mov bx,7c4h;  Starting address of memory map array
mov es,bx;
mov di,0h;

; use the INT 0x15, eax= 0xE820 BIOS function to get a memory map
; inputs: es:di -> destination buffer for 24 byte entries
; outputs: bp = entry count, trashes all registers except esi

do_e820:
    xor ebx, ebx        ; ebx must be 0 to start
    xor bp, bp      ; keep an entry count in bp
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; Place "SMAP" into edx
    mov eax, 0xe820
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1   ; force a valid ACPI 3.X entry
    mov ecx, 24     ; ask for 24 bytes
    int 0x15
    jc short .failed    ; carry set on first call means "unsupported function"
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; Some BIOSes apparently trash this register?
    cmp eax, edx        ; on success, eax must have been reset to "SMAP"
    jne short .failed
    test ebx, ebx       ; ebx = 0 implies list is only 1 entry long (worthless)
    je short .failed
    jmp short .jmpin
.e820lp:
    mov eax, 0xe820     ; eax, ecx get trashed on every int 0x15 call
    mov [es:di + 20], dword 1   ; force a valid ACPI 3.X entry
    mov ecx, 24     ; ask for 24 bytes again
    int 0x15
    jc short .e820f     ; carry set means "end of list already reached"
    mov edx, 0x0534D4150    ; repair potentially trashed register
.jmpin:
    jcxz .skipent       ; skip any 0 length entries
    cmp cl, 20      ; got a 24 byte ACPI 3.X response?
    jbe short .notext
    test byte [es:di + 20], 1   ; if so: is the "ignore this data" bit clear?
    je short .skipent
.notext:
    mov ecx, [es:di + 8]    ; get lower uint32_t of memory region length
    or ecx, [es:di + 12]    ; "or" it with upper uint32_t to test for zero
    jz .skipent     ; if length uint64_t is 0, skip entry
    inc bp          ; got a good entry: ++count, move to next storage spot
    add di, 24
.skipent:
    test ebx, ebx       ; if ebx resets to 0, list is complete
    jne short .e820lp
.e820f:
    mov [memMapLength], bp  ; store the entry count
    clc         ; there is "jc" on end of list to this point, so the carry must be cleared
    jmp .done
.failed:
    ;stc            ; "function unsupported" error exit 
    hlt
    ret
.done:
```

My code goes on and sets IDT and GDT then switches to protected mode. Here is the C code:

```
short memMapLength=0;
unsigned long availableMemBytes=0;

typedef struct memoryMapEntry{
    unsigned int baseLow;
    unsigned int baseHigh;
    unsigned long length;   
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int acpi_null; 
    } memoryMapEntry;

memoryMapEntry* memMapArr=0; 

void DetectMem(){
    memMapArr= (memoryMapEntry*)(0x00007c40);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<memMapLength;i++){
            if(memMapArr[i].type==1){           
                availableMemBytes += memMapArr[i].length;               
            }               
    }
}
```

In Assembly, I set the return buffer address `ES:DI` to `0x7c4:0` and catch this in C by pointing to `0x00007c40`. Is this possibly wrong? When I combine the assembly and C with `objconv` and compile them in NASM as binary, the resulting kernel tells me there is 1 byte of available memory when I run on VirtualBox. How do I resolve my problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your `memMapLength` gets propagated correctly to the C side? PS: learn to use a debugger

Comment: I just tested it. Changed mov [mamMapLength], bp to 200. The result is yes value is correctly sent

Comment: For a start, stop using "implementation defined" integers where you need something specific (e.g. don't use `unsigned long`, which is probably 32-bit and not 64-bit, when you need a 64-bit integer and should be using `uint64_t`).

Comment: Oh thank you ! :) this solved everyhing

Comment: *"copied from (somewhere)"* **!=** *"no error in that code"*, thats a **very** wrong assumption, i have seen microsoft MVPs posting utter bullshit on the internet even though they should be experts in that topic. Everyone is human, no matter how many degrees, titles, internet points and years of experience he/she has. **Never** trust anything *blindly*, **especially** if it is widely accepted but do **assume** that it may be *better* than re-inventing the wheel